# How to add extra option to the existing drush command?

Tags: hooks, drush

I'm trying to add extra option to the existing command as below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_drush_command_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_drush_command_alter(&$command) {
  if ($command['command'] == 'features-revert-all') {
    $command['options']['cleanup'] = dt("Remove non-existing components from the database after revert.");
  }
}
```

However it seems it doesn't work as expected and `drush fra --cleanup` fails.

Then the `help` command doesn't show this option either.

What's the proper way of adding such option, so drush can understand it and can be available for further parsing via `drush_get_option`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with [`drush_help_alter`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/hook_drush_help_alter/8.0.x) rather than [`drush_command_alter`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.api.php/function/hook_drush_command_alter/8.0.x). See the [example Drush policy file](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.1.0/examples/policy.drush.inc#L110), reproduced in part below:

```
function policy_drush_help_alter(&$command) {
  if ($command['command'] == 'updatedb') {
    $command['options']['token'] = 'Per site policy, you must specify a token in the --token option for all commands.';
  }
}
```