# How to make commands invoked by drush_invoke not to fail after adding extra option?

Tags: hooks, drush

I've added new option into drush command as suggested [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199561/1908):

```
function hook_drush_help_alter(&$command) {
  if ($command['command'] == 'features-revert-all') {
    $command['options']['cleanup'] = 'Remove non-existing components.';
  }
}
```

where `features-revert-all` is overridden by another created custom command as demonstrated [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199551/1908) (so basically another `custom-features-revert-all` command is called).

However when my custom command invoking another commands via `drush_invoke` - they fail, because they cannot find that option. I really don't care about the option whether they can recognise it or not, but they shouldn't fail.

So basically when I run:

```
drush fra --cleanup --yes
```

I've these errors:

> Unknown option: `--cleanup`.  See `drush help features-cleanup-feature` for available options. To suppress this error, add the option `--strict=0`.
>
> Unknown option: `--cleanup`.  See `drush help rules-revert-all` for available options. To suppress this error, add the option `--strict=0`.

Here is how my function look (simplified for clarity):

```
function drush_FOO_custom_features_revert_all() {
  module_load_include('inc', 'features', 'features.export');
  $force = drush_get_option('force');
  $cleanup = drush_get_option('cleanup'); // At this point, the option is working.

  $features_to_revert = features_get_features(NULL, TRUE);
  if ($cleanup) {
    drush_invoke("features-cleanup-feature", $features_to_revert);
  }
  else {
    drush_invoke("features-revert", $features_to_revert);
  }
  drush_invoke('rules-revert-all');
}
```

So basically the option works fine within the main function, but sub-commands are complaining that this option that it's unknown to them.

Question is, what's the correct approach of fixing it (so they won't fail)?

Do I need to add option to every other command which uses `drush_invoke` into `drush_help_alter`? Maybe there is some way of passing original drush options along. Or maybe I am forced to use `--strict=0`? Or there is some better way of fixing this issue?

Comment: I found something about that, when I was looking to implement a Drush command, but I cannot find it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred solution is to use `drush_invoke_process()` for subtasks. This will execute the command in its own process, completely isolate from the parent.

If you do need or wish to use `drush_invoke()` (doing so is a little faster, since you don't need to bootstrap again), then you should use `drush_set_option('strict', 0);` to disable options checking.